# Font problem with pypdf FreeText annotation

Tags: pypdf

I am writing a script that takes a pdf copy of an exam, and creates multiple copies, each with a different 3 digit number in the upper right hand corner. (This helps us create exams for the testing center.) I am using FreeText in the annotations library to do so:

```
pageno = FreeText(
    text = numberstring,
    rect = (box.width - 60,box.height - 60,box.width - 20,box.height - 20),
    font = "Arial",
    bold = True,
    italic = False,
    font_size = "20pt",
    font_color="000000",
    border_color  = "0000ff",
    background_color = None,
)
    writer.add_annotation(page_number=0,annotation = pageno)
```

This works *sort of well*, but has some issues.  (box comes from using mediabox to get the dimensions of the page).  It does create one pdf copy for each exam number, and it places the exam number in the upper right, but it does not seem to respect the font commands.  font_size, for example will not change the size of the font, and changing the font seems to do nothing.

No matter what I put for font_color, the color of the font defaults to what I put for border_color.
I suspect that it is not finding the font (I am on ubuntu), but am not sure.  I am doing something stupid here, because I don't see this type of error listed anywhere.

If anyone can see any issues, here, it would save what is remaining of my sanity.  If it would help to see the entire script, I can post it.  Thanks,

I tried changing Arial to a font in Ubuntu (I tried "Ubuntu"), and I also installed Arial.  Both results were identical.

I also changed border_color, and that's when I noticed it affects font_color.

Comment: You could go with a different approach: Create a single blank page with just the number in the format/style/postion you want. [fpdf2](https://pypi.org/project/fpdf2/) is excellent for that. Then use pypdf to merge the number-page with the exam-page.

Comment: Regarding the issue you face: It could also be a bug with pypdf. I suggest you take an example PDF (could be an empty one) and make a full example with your code + a screenshot + what you would have expected. With that you can file an issue at our issue tracker: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues - but the page merging is likely the quicker and more flexible solution

Comment: Thanks, Martin.  I didn't want a solution that required more than one library, because I wanted to make it easy for others to install.  But, maybe that's an unrealistic idea anyway.  I will try the separate page idea. I haven't heard of fpdf2, but I'll look at that.

Comment: Thank you. pdfcpu looks promising. I don't see how to avoid some programming, because I don't need page numbers - I need exam numbers on the front of each exam.  I'll look into it.